# Swift: can't load file using String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)

Tags: swift, exception, file-io

Seems like it should be simple. There are examples all over the place using `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)`, but none of them work for me. The main problem is that when I catch the exception, I can't figure out what exception it is. The doc speaks of exception codes, but it doesn't say what enum they belong to.

The file is a plain text file, I know it's there, and I have permissions to it. A lot of the Apple doc says that there's an `inout error` parameter that you can pass in, but that doc is clearly neglected by Apple, sorely outdated, and inconsistent with both itself and the compiler.

How can I figure out what the error is, or, is there a better way to load a text file than with `String(contentsOfFile:encoding:)`?

Comment: Error cases tend to be only available in Swift data types. The Foundation classes still return an `NSError`. You can get the error message by printing it out: `catch { print(error.localizedDescription }`

Comment: @CodeDifferent There's nowhere to get an NSError from. `String` returns nil, and there's no longer an `inout error` parameter in the call.

Comment: @CodeDifferent `print(error.localizedDescription)` is redundant. Just `print(error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "txt", inDirectory: "")
do {
    var myString = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
    // do something with myString
} catch {
    //error
}
```

Comment: Works great. I took your `encoding` parameter and plugged it into my failing code to replace `.utf8`, and now mine works great too. Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Terrible syntax. `let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Btw no need to use the inDirectory option passing an empty string. Just omit the last parameter.